# How can I write a test for controller with firebase factory in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, karma-jasmine

Since I wrote `firebase-factory` separately from `RecipeController`, I have an error in my Test.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$loaded' of undefined.
```

`$loaded` is a method in `firebase`...

test.js

```
describe('RecipeController', function() {
beforeEach(module('leChef'));

var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
  $controller = _$controller_;
}));

describe("$scope.calculateAverage", function() {
  it("calculates average correctly", function() {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('RecipeController', { $scope: $scope });

    $scope.calculateAverage();

    expect(average).toBe(sum/(Recipes.reviews.length-1));
  });
});
});
```

firebase-factory.js

```
app.factory("Recipes", ["$firebaseArray",
   function($firebaseArray) {
   var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-inferno-8595.firebaseio.com/recipes/");
   return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
]);
```

recipe-controller.js

```
 app.controller("RecipeController", ["$scope", "toastr", "$location", "$routeParams", "$compile", "Recipes",
 function($scope, toastr, $location, $routeParams, $compile, Recipes) {

$scope.recipes.$loaded().then(function(payload) {
  $scope.recipe = payload.$getRecord($routeParams.id);

  $scope.html = $scope.recipe.instructions;

  if (typeof $scope.recipe.reviews === "undefined") {
    $scope.recipe.reviews = [{}];
  }

  $scope.calculateAverage = function(AverageData){
    var sum = 0;

    if ($scope.recipe.reviews.length > 1) {
      for(var i = 1; i < $scope.recipe.reviews.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt($scope.recipe.reviews[i].stars, 10);
      }

      var average = sum/($scope.recipe.reviews.length-1);
      var roundedAverage = Math.round(average);
      return { 
        average: roundedAverage,
        markedStars: new Array(roundedAverage)
      };
    } else {
      return sum;
    }
  };
});
]);
```

Comment: Are you creating an array to get one item out of it? You can use `$firebaseObject` to get one item instead,

Answer (score 1):

In your `RecipeController` definition, you immediately call:

```
$scope.recipes.$loaded().then(function(payload) { ... }
```

...assuming that `$scope.recipes` is defined and has a property of `$loaded` -- which is not the case.

In your test:

```
describe("$scope.calculateAverage", function() {
  it("calculates average correctly", function() {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('RecipeController', { $scope: $scope });

    $scope.calculateAverage();

    expect(average).toBe(sum/(Recipes.reviews.length-1));
  });
});
```

...you define scope as an empty object, then inject it into your controller.

Assuming you are using Jasmine as a test framework, you could [create a spy](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) like this:

```
var $scope = {
    recipes: {
        $loaded: function() { /* this is a mock function */ }
    }
};
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve({
    /* this is the data you expect back from $scope.recipes.$loaded */
});
var promise = deferred.promise;
spyOn($scope.recipes, '$loaded').and.returnValue(promise);
```

This is just one of many ways you could stub out that function and control the data you get in your test. It assumes a basic understanding of [the $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and [the Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

**Best Practices**

It is best not to attach data to the `$scope` service. I would recommend reading up on [the controllerAs syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/), if you're not familiar with it.

TL;DR: A controller is just a JavaScript "class", and the definition function is its constructor. Use `var vm = this;` and then attach variables to the instance reference `vm` (as in "view model", or whatever you want to call it) instead.

Rather than relying on `$scope.recipes` to have been defined elsewhere, you should explicitly define it in your controller. If `recipes` are defined in another controller, create a service that both controllers can share.

Comment: Hi! Shaun thanks for you tipp!! I have been trying what you suggested.

Comment: But I have another error.  $scope.calculateAverage() method does not exist.  Could you please give me more tips? [link](http://pastebin.com/0YRPerdc) Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: In your test, $scope is only going to have what you put in it. The real problem you have is that you are creating implicit dependencies in your app by attaching things to $scope in one place and expecting it to be there in another. It becomes very hard to test your controllers and services when they have these hidden dependencies.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem on http://plnkr.co and post a link, I'll be happy to fork it and make it work.